# what is the bracket used for in making an instance on android?

Tags: java, android, button

for example like this code.

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

what is the bracket() in the button used for?

Comment: are you talking about (Button)

Comment: you explicitly need to find a Button because you are assigning it to a Button variable.

Answer (score 5):

The bracket around the Button says - **You are casting the view as Button.**